# how to properly align navigation bar of my web-page?

Tags: html, css

I have created navigation bar on my web-page and I've taken help from W3School(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp) for this. I want to place navigational links on right side and their order should be from 'left to right'. But the position(order) of buttons are from 'right to left' as shown in below figure. Can somebody guide me where am I doing mistake in my code? I am beginner to web development.

[image]

[image]

> Desired Output should be something like this:

[image]

> another example

[image]

> Order

[image]

> Here is my code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}


.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#37312f;
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

 .topnav a.logo {
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: #fff;
                }

   .topnav-right {
            float:left;
            /*height: 53px;*/
        }


.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -de1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
       <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about `DropDown` its not in your `Desired Output`?

Comment: let me update the given link.

Comment: Looks like a style issue, what is the relevance for the C# tag? removing the irrelevant tag

Comment: So your desired output should be on left side or right side of page?

Comment: output should be on right side, but order of buttons/links should be from left to right. I m supposing order of English alphabets here. As we write alphabets from left to right.

Comment: @Emmy, I added my answer below, **Run the snippet** to test an output.

Comment: @Emmy, did you checked my answer. I used standard *bootstrap* way to achieve output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **`.topnav a`** css class contains

```
float: right;
```

And **`.dropdown`** css class also contains

```
float: right;
```

Change it to `float: left;`

```
.topnav a {
    float: left;               <= Change here from right to left
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;              <= Change here from right to left
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also change in **`.topnav-right`** css class,

```
.topnav-right {
    float: right;            <= Change here left to right
}
```

And make your chnages in HTML like

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <div class="topnav-right">
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

So finally your code will be,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial
        }


        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #37312f;
            padding: 12px 14px;
        }

            .topnav a {
                float: left;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 12px 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

                .topnav a.logo {
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: #fff;
                }

        .topnav-right {
            float: right;
        }


        .active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .dropdown .dropbtn {
                font-size: 17px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 12px 14px;
                background-color: inherit;
                font-family: inherit;
                margin: 0;
            }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: -de1;
        }

            .dropdown-content a {
                float: none;
                color: black;
                padding: 12px 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

        .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }

                .topnav.responsive .icon {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }

                .topnav.responsive a {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
                    float: none;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
                    position: relative;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: left;
                }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <div class="topnav-right">
                <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#news">News</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">
                        Dropdown
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-left:16px">
            <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
            <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
                if (x.className === "topnav") {
                    x.className += " responsive";
                } else {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an comprehensive answer. Now I am able to get the logic where I were mistaken.

Comment: glad to hear, if it solves your problem then please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and upvote also if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Just removed `float:right` from **topnav a** and added `display:flex` to **.topnav**, so that it will be aligned in line horizontally.

When your are applying **float-right** to each `<a>` element, **CSS** individually floating them to the right which leads to the inversion of order.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}


.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#37312f;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

 .topnav a.logo {
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: #fff;
                }

   .topnav-right {
            float:left;
            /*height: 53px;*/
        }


.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -de1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
       <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually I do not want to move my navigational links on other side. They should be placed on the side(right) I have shown in desired output

Comment: @Emmy okay, I have edited my answer and added content ailgnment to it. Just check it once.

Comment: I am working visual studio(C#) and here I am getting error on display: `display:flex;` 'validation (css 3.0) flex is not a valid value for the display property'. What to do now?

Comment: @Emmy It seems like your using older version of vs. Get it updated it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont detect any mistake try to copy this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```